# Xcode cannot run using this device

Tags: iphone, xcode

First of all I know that there are already questions like this asked but I could not find an answer so I decided to just ask myself. I am using an iphone 5s for my testing and I have 64 bit arm7 and everything on but after I did a clean I somehow get a message saying:Xcode cannot run using the selected device choose a supporting architecture in order to run on this device.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check your app it support for x64 bit architecture if it is not change to like below

[image]